# Converting incoming XML to JSON in a wso2 ESB 4.6.0 Proxy

Tags: xml, json, wso2, wso2-esb

I have a proxy which takes incoming XML and preforms an xslt transform on it to get the required xml format.
It should then be sent to the service as JSON so i've set the messageType as application/json however it arrives as XML.

```
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="XSLTTRANSPROXY_BRYN" transports="https,http" statistics="disable" trace="disable" startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <xslt key="gov:/Complete.xsl">
            <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="GUID" expression="fn:substring-after(get-property('MessageID'), 'urn:uuid:')"/>
         </xslt>
        <property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"/>
         <log level="full"/>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
      <endpoint>
         <address uri="http://localhost:54150/"/>
      </endpoint>
   </target>
   <description></description>
</proxy>
```

I've tried various types of builders in the axis2.xml file however none seem to change the result.
Currently running WSO2 ESB 4.6.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Code should be like this:

```
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="XSLTTRANSPROXY_BRYN" transports="https,http" statistics="disable" trace="disable" startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <xslt key="gov:/Complete.xsl">
            <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="GUID" expression="fn:substring-after(get-property('MessageID'), 'urn:uuid:')"/>
         </xslt>
        <property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"/>
         <log level="full"/>
<send>
<endpoint>
         <address uri="http://localhost:54150/"/>
      </endpoint>
</send>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
         </target>
   <description></description>
</proxy>
```

And you need to enable the tags mentioned in this document:- http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB403/ESB+and+JSON. If you are not getting data in json try the service in other browser

Comment: I've made a clean install of wso2esb 4.6, set the proxy to the above, made sure the axis2.xml contains both the messagebuilder and formatter and put axis2-json-1.6.2.jar and jettison-1.3.3.jar in the lib folder however the content type is still arriving at TCPMon as application/xml.
Is there a way I can confirm that the formatters and builders are available?
What else could it be?

Comment: After upgrading to ESB 4.7.0 this above worked. Unsure why it wasn't working in 4.6.0.

Answer (score 1):

Your proxy should work with no issue. When we set,

```
<property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"/>
```

message will turn into json by message formatter. So if we log before send, its still in xml format. You can see the converted message using a tool like tcpmon.

I tested following sample, pointing to tcpmon.

```
<proxy name="TestProxy"
          transports="https http"
          startOnLoad="true"
          trace="disable">
      <description/>
      <target>
         <endpoint>
            <address uri="http://localhost:8888/"/>
         </endpoint>
         <inSequence>
            <property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"/>
            <log level="full"/>
         </inSequence>
         <outSequence>
            <send/>
         </outSequence>
      </target>
   </proxy>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the instructions on the following link
http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB403/ESB+and+JSON